# Run exe with javascript and get response

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, activexobject

Here is my code for running exe using javascript.
It's working fine.
Is there a way for me to know:

1. When the exe closed.
2. Get a return value from this app.

Also, what is the difference between using ShellExecute & Run?

```
     var sExePath = "c:\\Debug\\WebToCardReader_Test.exe";
     var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
     var oExec = oShell.ShellExecute(sExePath, "", "", "open", "1");
```

Comment: Is the .exe a command-line application?

Comment: it's a regular c# winform.

Comment: Which of your two requirements does your code currently satisfy?

Comment: None. it just opens the exe.

Comment: Even after the exe closes? You don't get a return value in `oExec`?

Comment: I didn't check :). I thought it's just a boolean with 0/1. Isn't it? can I get a string with some real data in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky.aspx) allows you to set the boolean `bWaitOnReturn` flag, which blocks your script until the program returns.
2. On that page, the VBScript sample simply assigns the command to a variable (as you've done with `ShellExecute`). I'm not sure if this works in JavaScript, but it's worth a shot.

   However, as you know, [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does allow you to store a return value.